# Awk: parsing inline code spans in markdown

Tags: awk, markdown

I'm trying to write a simple Markdown parser in `awk`, somewhat because I haven't found a good terminal-only markdown parser, but mostly because I'm interested in learning to use `awk` better.  The object is to parse the markdown, and all code snippets ( both inline code spans and code blocks) should be printed to the terminal using the "reverse" font attribute (more markdown styles like bold, italic, etc. will be addressed later).

My current code:

````
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    normal="\033[0m";
    reverse="\033[7m";
}
/```/ {
    code_block = ! code_block;
    next;
}
/`(.*)`/ {
   printf "%s", print_alt( "\1", reverse)
}
{
    if (code_block) {
        printf "%s\n", print_alt($0, reverse)
    } else {
        print $0
    }
    next;
}
END {}


function print_alt (the_string, escape_seq) {
    return sprintf("%s%s%s", escape_seq, the_string, normal)
}
````

For a markdown file like this:

````
This docker project is intended to run zeppelin in a docker container, complete with the hadoop and spark clients configured to work with the hadoop cluster.


For OSX:

Prerequisites (available through brew install):
 - docker
 - docker-machine
 - virtualbox

First, ensure that you have a virtual machine set up for docker-machine. You can create one named `dockermachine` with:
```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dockermachine
```

If the vm is running, stop it.
```
docker-machine stop dockermachine
```

Next, set up port the forwarding rules.
```
VBoxManage modifyvm dockermachine --natpf1 "zeppelinPF1,tcp,,4194,,4194"
VBoxManage modifyvm dockermachine --natpf1 "zeppelinPF2,tcp,,4195,,4195"
VBoxManage modifyvm dockermachine --natpf1 "zeppelinPF3,tcp,,4196,,4196"
VBoxManage modifyvm dockermachine --natpf1 "zeppelinPF4,tcp,,8080,,8080"
```
````

I have the block-code working fine: e.g. it correctly prints the lines starting with docker-machine and VBoxManage in reverse font to the terminal.  But, I can't get the syntax for the inline-code span to work (i.e. the word "dockermachine" should be printed in reverse mode).

Comment: Awk doesn't support the back-referencing into the pattern that it looks like you're trying to do with `print_alt( "\1", ...`.  You'll have to find another way to deconstruct the lines with back ticks and reconstructing them with reverse text as appropriate.

Comment: Do you have or can you get GNU awk?

Comment: jas: that's... pretty much what i'm asking?

Comment: @EdMorton: yes, i can get `gawk` via Mac homebrew.

Comment: Then to use a capture group like you appear to be trying to do is: `match($0,/'(.*)'/,a) { printf "%s", print_alt( a[1], reverse) }`. I had to change the quotes just for display in this comment.

Comment: That's really close, but it prints the text at the beginning of the line, rather than in-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU **awk** solution: I used your code, did some cleaning up and came up with this:

````
$ cat tst3.awk
BEGIN {
  normal="\033[0m";
  reverse="\033[7m";
}
/^```/{
   p=(++p % 2)
   next
}
p{ 
   $0=print_alt($0, reverse)
}
/`/{                                                   
   s=$0
   while (match(s, /([^`]*)`([^`]+)`/, arr)){          # we need a loop here
      printf "%s%s", arr[1], print_alt(arr[2],reverse) # because line can contain 
      s=substr(s, RLENGTH+1)                           # multiple `str`'s  
   }
   print s
   next
}1
function print_alt(str, escape_seq){
   return sprintf("%s%s%s", escape_seq, str, normal)
}
````

The breakdown of the regex used:

```
([^`]*)         # group 1, capture 0.. chars ne to `
`([^`]+)`       # enclosed by `, group 2, which captures at least one chars ne to `
```

`brew install gawk` will install GNU awk 4.1.4 for you on MacOSX.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because it had an explanation of the regexes involved and because it doesn't change the FS, which makes it more extensible for the other markdown elements.

Answer (score 1):

I THINK this is what you're looking for:

````
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    normal="<NRM>"      # normal="\033[0m"
    reverse="<REV>"     # reverse="\033[7m"
    FS="`"
}
/```/ {
    code_block = ! code_block
    next
}
{
    if (code_block) {
        printf "%s", print_alt($0, reverse)
    }
    else {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%s", (i%2 ? $i : print_alt($i, reverse))
        }
    }
    print ""
}

function print_alt (the_string, escape_seq) {
    return sprintf("%s%s%s", escape_seq, the_string, normal)
}
````

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
This docker project is intended to run zeppelin in a docker container, complete with the hadoop and spark clients configured to work with the hadoop cluster.


For OSX:

Prerequisites (available through brew install):
 - docker
 - docker-machine
 - virtualbox

First, ensure that you have a virtual machine set up for docker-machine. You can create one named <REV>dockermachine<NRM> with:
<REV>docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dockermachine<NRM>

If the vm is running, stop it.
<REV>docker-machine stop dockermachine<NRM>

Next, set up port the forwarding rules.
<REV>VBoxManage modifyvm dockermachine --natpf1 "zeppelinPF1,tcp,,4194,,4194"<NRM>
<REV>VBoxManage modifyvm dockermachine --natpf1 "zeppelinPF2,tcp,,4195,,4195"<NRM>
<REV>VBoxManage modifyvm dockermachine --natpf1 "zeppelinPF3,tcp,,4196,,4196"<NRM>
<REV>VBoxManage modifyvm dockermachine --natpf1 "zeppelinPF4,tcp,,8080,,8080"<NRM>
```

That will work in any awk and will hand multiple tick-encased strings per line.